# Java: efficient way to remember which objects are processed

Tags: java, performance, optimization, hash, hashset

What is the most efficient way to remember which objects are processed?

Obviously one could use a hash set:

```
Set<Foo> alreadyProcessed = new HashSet<>();

void process(Foo foo) {
    if (!alreadyProcessed.contains(foo)) {
        // Do something
        alreadyProcessed.add(foo);
    }
}
```

This makes me wonder why I would store the object, while I just want to check if the hash does exist in this set. Assuming that any hash of foo is unique.

Is there any more performant way to do this?

Take in mind that a very large number of objects will be processed and that the actual process code will not always be very heavy. Also it is not possible for me to have a precompiled worklist of objects, it will be build up dynamically during the processing.

Comment: It depends on need - you either need 1) the original object or; 2) some way to identify a particular object / task as 'been processed'. If keeping hold of object it cannot be GC'ed - *if and only if* this would keep the object alive *far too long* then it could be a form of a memory leak. (From a 'performance' view the JVM/GC is also a bit better at eliminating short-lived objects.) Thus there really is no 'optimization' here, only doing what is required.

Comment: Anyway, the usage of `hashCode()` is flawed. An appropriate *unique* task token would need to be used. This is because two objects with the *same* hash code might not be equals (eg. might not represent the same value). Even if the custom `hashCode` made some sort of guarantee it is sketchy to use as such.

Comment: @user2864740 The process method is 'hotcode' in the application I'm working on. It'll will be called very often, with a large number of objects (foo). I understand that this might look like a micro-optimisation, but I thing a more performant solutions would really speed up my application.

Comment: If there is any concern about 'performance' this *first* thing should be a  generating *holistic performance benchmarks*. Otherwise such micro-optimization questions appear when - unless this code process an fsvo amount of items or runs for fsvo amount of time - such Just Doesn't Matter. Go by the 97/3 rule.

Comment: Some code in the process functions (`// Do something`) look like `t += foo.x;`. I do not really want to benchmark something I know that will increase performance.

Comment: I urge following the 97/3 rule. In this case see my first two comments. It is *not* about performance here (until there is a benchmark to prove otherwise - and there is not even an 'interesting' algorithmic complexity problem to discuss), but rather about *algorithm need* and *correctness*.

Comment: If you do not have to guarantee to process every object **at most once** you can use something like a weak HashSet `Set<Object> weakHashSet = Collections.newSetFromMap(
        new WeakHashMap<Object, Boolean>());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Set#contains` can be very fast. It depends how are your `hashcode()` and `equals()` methods are implemented. try to cache the *hashcode value* to make it more faster. (like String.java)
2. The other simple and fastes option is to add a boolean member to your Foo class: `foo.done = true;`

Answer (score 2):

**Write good code. Optimize it for performance only if you can show that you need to in your use case.**

There is no performance advantage in storing a hash code rather than the object. If you doubt that, remember that what is being stored is a *reference* to the object, not a copy of it. In reality that's going to be 64 bits, pretty much the same as the hash code. You've already spent a substantial amount of time thinking about a problem that none of your users will ever notice. (If you are doing this calculations millions of times in a tight, mission-critical loop that's another matter).

Using the set is simple to understand. Doing anything else runs a risk that a future maintainer will not understand the code and introduce a bug.

Also don't forget that a hash code it not guaranteed to be unique for every different object. Every so often storing the hash code will give you a false positive, causing you to fail to process an object you wanted to process. (As an aside, you need to make sure that equals() only considers two objects equal if they are the same object. The default Object.equals() does this, so don't override it)

Use the Set. If you are processing a very large number of objects, use a more efficient Set than HashSet. That is much more likely to give you a performance speedup than anything clever with hashing.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the hashcode since equality of the hashcode of two objects does not imply that the objects are equal.

Else depending on the use case you want to remember if you have already processed

- a) the same object, tested by reference, or
- b) an equal object, tested by a call to `Object.equals(Object)`

For b) you can use a standard `Set` implementation.

For a) also you can also use a standard `Set` implementation if you now that the equals-method is returning equality of references, or you would need something like a [IdentityHashSet](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/dev/util/collect/IdentityHashSet.java?r=9858).

No mention of performance in this answer, you need to address correctness first!